# A error about 800700c1

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

When I run a C# example from sterling website.It appeared an error 'Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {B9A792C1-9922-4DF7-B4AC-994EC261D92C} component failed due to the following error: 800700c1.'.The error code is `private SterlingLib.STIOrderMaint stiMaint = new SterlingLib.STIOrderMaint();`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Sorry to say, this isn't something the community can help you with. Please consider reposting the question with more specifics. What is "sterling?" What are you trying to do? What does your failing code look like?

Comment: I guess I'm not part of the community.  This is a very common error, ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT.  Right-click your EXE project.  Properties, Build tab, change the Platform target setting from AnyCPU to x86.  Using a .NET 4 assembly in a project that targets a lesser version may cause it too but this is surely a 32-bit component problem given the COM angle and the vendor name.

Comment: I tried that, but i failed.Do you mean when i run this code in 64-bit system ,it will be OK ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Sterling ActiveX API in my code before. Maybe you should log in to Sterling before executing your program. Without login, instances of some interfaces can't be created.